# rqt then choosing rviz plugin -> core dump

Tags: rviz, plugin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start rqt and choose rviv plugin (in groovy):

```
tompe@heyer:~$ rqt
python: /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/include/OgreSingleton.h:80: Ogre::Singleton<T>::Singleton() [with T = Ogre::LogManager]: Assertion `!ms_Singleton' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is really this so buggy that it does not even start?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51674/rqt-then-choosing-rviz-plugin--%3E-core-dump/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-08**:
What Linux distro and release are you running?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-01-08**:
I tested in Ubuntu 12.04 (i686). The same problem at home with 12.04 (x86_64).

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-07**:
Seems to work now for me with the latest version of the groovy Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can confirm this on 12.04 (x64)/Groovy.  I found a related issue on github already: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/553.  There are a few similar issues in the rqt tracker that have been closed, so perhaps it hasn't been pushed out to the public yet?

**EDIT**

I believe that this fixes it https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/560 (it does on my system).

It's a one-line edit, so it should be pretty easy to patch rviz and build from source on your own system.

**EDIT 2**

Fixed in latest debs.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-01-09**:
It still does not work after today's groovy package updates.

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2013-01-09**:
I have exactly the same issue, under Ubuntu 12.04, groovy (under virtual box).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-10**:
Re your fix: Should there be a `new` in the `getSingletonPtr` line? (I haven't checked or tested anything! Just looks odd to me)

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-01-10**:
I believe that getSingletonPtr returns a pointer to the already-created instance, and is not allocating a new instance.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-01-10**:
The OGRE docs indicate that if you bring up an OgreRoot before you bring up a LogManager, it will instantiate one for you, thus causing the singleton assert error when you try to re-instantiate.  The LogManager constructor should only be called before OgreRoot, which is not what is happening.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-10**:
I was only referring to the diff in the pull request. It does something like `new getSingletonPtr()` instead of just `getsSingletonPtr()`, but I really haven't checked or tested anything in that regard. Just looked wrong to me.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-01-10**:
Ah, sorry about that.  Yes, that pull request is incorrect, and the problem is also a little bit deeper.  It appears as though Dave has already come up with a fix that will be released shortly.